# Lotus Notes NAB - Adding a field

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a project that I need to put an **Internet Address** and also add a new field called **ShortName** for all **groups** in the **Notes NAB**.

I am able to put the values and save the document , I tried with a doc.save and a computewithform.  This is the Group form.

After the change, people in that group are no longer able to access the application.

Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong ?

User A is in group XYZ.

I added internetaddress xyz.com and a shortname text field xyzmigration

Application A is having an ACL with the group XYZ as editor.  When User A tries to open the Application A, he get a not authorize.  If I delete both values, User A is able to open the database.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are these users client or web users?

Comment: they are trying to access Notes DB via the client.  They tried Ctrl-F5 to be sure to have the right credential.

Comment: I wonder if it might be the name of the field you used?  "Shortname" has special significance in Person documents, and while it's not on the Group form, when the ACL comes in to play, who knows what it's looking at.  Could you try using a different field name and see if that's what it was?

Comment: I thought of that me too, I tried another field name and I had the same problem :(

Comment: just to be clear - you both set InternetAddress field and Shortname field in the Group document? And that's all that takes to break it down?

Comment: How are you creating the fields/setting the values? Can you post your Lotusscript code?

Comment: Another thought: maybe setting the internet address causes the group to be considered mail-only. Make sure the group is set to Multi-purpose.

Comment: If ( collection.Count <> 0 ) Then

   Set doc = collection.getfirstdocument
   doc.InternetAddress = InternetAddressValue
     
   success = doc.ComputeWithForm( False, False )
                                                                                  If success Then
  Call doc.Save( True, False )
End If
     
Else  '
End If '( collection.Count = 0 )

Answer (score 0):

$ServerAccess view validates Group documents and omits any Groups that has Shortname field present.

Comment: Then how do you explain OP's observation that the problem occurred with a field of a different name?

Comment: He probably didn't delete the shortname that he added. That's my guess :-)

Comment: Normunds, I think you gave me a track of solution with the $ServerAccess view.  The group is in the view, but after I add the 2 fields, it dissapear from that view.  I need to check the selection formula of that view.  Thanks a lot, I will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Normunds has the correct answer, but I want to add a suggestion: create a new group instead of modifying the existing group.  I.e., if the group is "MyGroup", create a group named "MyGroup_Extended" and set it up with

- Shortname = the value that you want
- InternetAddress = the value that you want
- Members = "MyGroup"

That way, you leave MyGroup untouched, but you still have a modified group document with the additional information added and the same member list.

And another thing: In order to make those groups that you already altered functional again, you should run a simple agent against all of the groups that does this:

```
FIELD ShortName := @DeleteField;
FIELD InternetAddress := @DeleteField;
```

Answer (score 0):

After the help of some answers that I got here.  I checked the view $ServerAccess.  The selection formula is checking for a field Shortname and that is what was causing my problem.  I will create another field name and we will be able to use this field instead of ShortName.                                                                allfields := @DocFields;
test1 := 0;
test2 := 0;
@For(i:=1; i < @Elements(allfields); i:=i+1; test1 := test1 + @If(@UpperCase(allfields[i]) = "LISTNAME";1;0));
@For(i:=1; i < @Elements(allfields); i:=i+1; test2:=test2 + @If(@UpperCase(allfields[i]) = "SHORTNAME";1;0));
SELECT (test1 < 2 & test2 = 0 &Type = "Group" & (@IsUnavailable ( GroupType)|GroupType="0" : "2":"3":"4")) & Form="Group" & @IsUnavailable($Conflict)
Thanks for your help.